# Bash script being passed one parameter, but I want multiple

Tags: bash

I have this simple script to print out what it receives and then just exits:

```
IFS="|${IFS}";
echo "$# parameters";
echo Using '$*';
for p in $*;
do
    echo "[$p]";
done;
echo Using '"$*"';
for p in "$*";
do
    echo "[$p]";
done;
echo Using '$@';
for p in $@;
do
    echo "[$p]";
done;
echo Using '"$@"';
for p in "$@";
do
    echo "[$p]";
done
```

If I execute: `./echoparams This is a "test target"` It will print out:

```
4 parameters
Using $*
[This]
[is]
[a]
[Test]
[target]
Using "$*"
[This|is|a|Test target]
Using $@
[This]
[is]
[a]
[Test]
[target]
Using "$@"
[This]
[is]
[a]
[Test target]
```

**The problem:**

I have an external program (which I cannot modify) passing this into my script, but when it executes it prints out this:

```
1 parameters
Using $*
[This]
[is]
[a]
["test]
[target"]
Using "$*"
[This is a "test target"]
Using $@
[This]
[is]
[a]
["test]
[target"]
Using "$@"
[This is a "test target"]
```

I have a hunch that it is actually passing `"This is a \"test target\""` into the script.  ***How can I take this "one parameter" and make it into "multiple parameters" but still respecting the combined words (with quotes surrounding it)?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
eval set "$@"
```

or (safer if it might begin with shell options):

```
eval set -- "$@"
```

After that you should be able to use `"$@"`.

As with all `eval`s, this has all kinds of dangers. :-)

Example of a danger:

```
$ set '`ls`'
$ eval set -- "$@"
$ echo $#
28
$ echo "$1"
COPYRIGHT
```

---

Edit: here's a `protect` shell function and an example of using it.  I am not sure I protected against everything, but it gets the two obvious cases:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

protect()
{
    local quoted

    quoted="${1//$/\\\$}"
    quoted="${quoted//\`/\\\`}"
    # use printf instead of echo in case $1 is (eg) -n
    printf %s "$quoted"
}

foo=expanded

set -- '-e -n $foo `ls` "bar baz"'
eval set -- "$@"
echo "without protect, \$# is $#:"
for arg do echo "[$arg]"; done

set -- '-e -n $foo `ls` "bar baz"'
eval set -- $(protect "$@")
echo "with protect, \$# is $#"
for arg do echo "[$arg]"; done
```

When I run it:

```
without protect, $# is 46:
[-e]
[-n]
[expanded]
[OUT]
[a.py]
[ast_ex.py]
  ---snipped remaining ls output for space reasons---
[bar baz]
with protect, $# is 5
[-e]
[-n]
[$foo]
[`ls`]
[bar baz]
```

If other characters need quoting, it's obvious how to add them to `protect`.

Comment: Would there be any other way than using `eval`?

Comment: There's always another way.  Other "easy" ways, though?  Nothing obvious off-hand.  It might be worth running "$@" through a filter to substitute "dangerous" characters (dollar sign and backquote at least).  I've written this up as a test, I'll edit it in.

Comment: The `eval` would leave you with four arguments, 'This', 'is', 'a' and 'test target' — but the double quote would have been removed as `"test` and `target"` were interpreted and grouped together.  But `eval` is basically as good as it gets.

Comment: I've ended up just using eval.  Thanks!